# 'Account' object has no attribute 'orderproduct' The downlad and preview is not shwoing

Tags: python, django

I want a situation, when the user purchases the product, and orderproduct created, he can download the image..

This is the product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # managers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="product_manager")
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    media = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=download_media_location, storage = FileSystemStorage(location=(protected_uploads_loc)))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=15.99)
    sale_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=9.99, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    image_size = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    # date_taken = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
```

This is the orderproduct model

```
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # download = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="download_product")
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is the product download views

```
class ProductDownloadView(MultiSlugMixin, DetailView):
    model = Product
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        # if obj in request.user.myproducts.products.all():
        if obj in request.user.orderproduct.product_set.all():
            filepath = Path.joinpath(settings.PROTECTED_UPLOADS, obj.media.path)
            print(filepath)
            guessed_type = guess_type(filepath)[0]
            wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filepath, "rb"))
            mimetype = "application/force-download"
            if guessed_type:
                mimetype = guessed_type
            response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type=mimetype)
            if not request.GET.get("preview"):
                response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; file=%s"%(obj.media.name)
            response['X-SendFile'] = str(obj.media.name)
            return response
        else:
            raise Http404
```

This is the html template

```
 {% if request.user.is_authenticated and object.media and object in request.user.orderproduct.product_set.all %}
     <p>
         <a href="{{ object.get_download }}">Download</a>
         <a href="{{ object.get_download }}?preview=True">Preview</a>
     </p>
 {% else %}
     <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xl js-scroll-trigger p-3"
        href="{% url 'cart:add_cart' product.id %}">ADD TO CART</a>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on a django project. I want a situation, when user can download the image after completing payment. But after completing the payment, the download and preview option is not showing. And When i go to the download link, it will show 'Account' object has no attribute 'orderproduct'

Comment: The orderproduct models and the product are related with a foreignkey. But, If i use a manytomany relationship, it will come through. What am I doing wrong.